# How to install ElasticSearch without setting JAVA_HOME globally

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to install ElasticSearch on my machine. The goal is to install everything without setting JAVA_HOME as it may interfere with other software

I downloaded the latest JRE and installed it. At this stage JAVA_HOME is not set and that's exactly what I was expecting

Then, I ran the following:

> elasticsearch-service.bat install elasticsearch-service
>   "C:\path_to_my_jre"

First problem: if the path to my JRE contains whitespaces the command will fail. If I place the JRE on a path without whitespaces it works fine.

After some struggling the ElasticSearch service is now installed correctly

Unfortunately if I try to run the service (from the Windows services panel) it doesn't start, the log file states that JAVA_HOME is not set.

It is possible to avoid setting JAVA_HOME globally? Setting it would mean interfering with other applications and I don't want to take that risk

I noticed that the Windows service being created calls the elasticsearc-service-x64.exe passing it a weird parameter \RS.... . What's that parameter? Can I pass a custom JRE path to that executable and avoid setting JAVA_HOME alltogether?

Comment: You can set java_home just for that command https://superuser.com/questions/1049430/how-do-you-set-environment-variables-for-a-single-command-on-windows

Comment: ok, but how can I set JAVA_HOME and launch the executable atomically as a Windows service? Using && ?

Comment: RS is RunService parameter of Apache Service Wrapper. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/

Comment: can I specify my path to the JRE as a parameter?